# How does the userQuota limitations works on YouTube Data API V3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm building an alternative client for YouTube subscriptions browsing (folder based subscriptions with according feed generated), and I'm making a lot of requests to YouTube to aggregate that data.

I'm caching a lot of requests as it is not needed to refresh them once it has been fetched on any other day before the current one.

The fact is, current-day refreshes are consuming a lot, and I reach my quota pretty fast even though those requests are read-only.

I submitted that YouTube quota increase request form, but still, I'm quite afraid.

Am I missing something with the userIp & quotaUser parameters ?

Shouldn't those requests - as they are pretty much the same that a normal user would do on the regular YouTube client - be considered as "Queries per 100 seconds per user" ?

My main quota, the "Queries per day" currently seems to handle ALL the requests coming from my app, even though I added the quotaUser parameter on all my requests made by a user on the frontend.

I think I am missing something as my app should not be considered as "data consuming" as it is sending almost nothing to YouTube in terms of data, and it is just reading data that is also available on the YouTube main client, but not in the same format..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I haven't been able to get information about `userQuota` can you provide a reference please ?